# Find method in subclass based on dynamic parameter call in base class in C#

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have a base class with a method that accepts an interface. I want to find the method that best matches this interface in the subclass. For example:

```
abstract class Base<T>
{
  public T Get(IParam parameter){
    return Provide(parameter as dynamic);
  }

  public abstract T Provide(IParam parameter);
}

class Impl<string> : Base<string>
{
  public string Provide(IParam parameter)
  {
    return "default value";
  }

  public string Provide(ParamImplementation1 parameter)
  {
    return "value for implementation 1";
  }

  public string Provide(ParamImplementation2 parameter)
  {
    return "value for implementation 2";
  }
}
```

Unfortunately The default value is returned every time. It seems like the dynamic keyword doesn't work when the actual implementation is in the subclass. Is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: the dynamic keyword here doesn't make any difference, the implementation of an abstract method must have its same signature exactly. That is why only Provide(IParam parameter) is called every time, and that would never change in this case.

Comment: The overloads for `ParamImplementation1` and `ParamImplementation1` are not part of the base abstract class so when `Base` calls `Provide` it's only going to return the `IParam` version that it knows about.

Answer (score 2):

So the solution seems to be to cast `this` to `dynamic`, like so:

```
abstract class Base<T>
{
  public T Get(IParam parameter){
    return (this as dynamic).Provide(parameter as dynamic);
  }

  public abstract T Provide(IParam parameter);
}

class Impl<string> : Base<string>
{
  public string Provide(IParam parameter)
  {
    return "default value";
  }

  public string Provide(ParamImplementation1 parameter)
  {
    return "value for implementation 1";
  }

  public string Provide(ParamImplementation2 parameter)
  {
    return "value for implementation 2";
  }
}
```

Comment: The `dynamic` is known to use reflection internally. As I mentioned, reflection is the only option I see. You've found the most compact way. Excellent job! +1

Answer (score 1):

Why not check the real type of the `parameter` in the `Provide` method override?

```
private abstract class Base<T>
{
    public T Get(IParam parameter)
    {
        return Provide(parameter);
    }

    public abstract T Provide(IParam parameter);
}

private class Impl : Base<string>
{
    public override string Provide(IParam parameter)
    {
        if (parameter is ParamImplementation1)
            return "value for implementation 1";
        if (parameter is ParamImplementation2)
            return "value for implementation 2";
        return "default value";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of making the method generic? It works the same way without that.

Comment: @DavidG I agree, there is no need of generics, my bad.

Comment: I have quite a lot of different implementations of IParam, each one with different properties. Having one huge method with many ifs makes it hard to understand and hard to test.

Comment: Do you have a lot of `Base<T>` implementations also? If so, I only can see the *reflection* to be a possible solution.

Comment: @Dmitry I've answered my own question. The solution I found was to cast `this` to `dynamic`.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle that in your default `provide(IParam param)` method.

```
private readonly IDictionary<Type, MethodInfo> _methods;

public Impl() {
    var methods = this.GetType().GetMethods(
        BindingFlags.Public |
        BindingFlags.NonPublic |
        BindingFlags.Instance |
        BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

    var provide = methods
        .Where(m => m.Name.Equals("Provide", StringComparison.Ordinal) && m.GetParameters().Length == 1)
        .ToList();

    _methods = when.ToDictionary(m => m.GetParameters().First().ParameterType, m => m);
}

public string Provide(IParam param) {
    MethodInfo methodInfo;
    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(param.GetType(), out methodInfo)) {
        return methodInfo.Invoke(this, new object[] { param });
    }

    return "default value";
}
```

So you check your class for methods with the name `Provide` and save it in a dictionary. I would store this dictionary in a class member for performance reasons. Then you can ask the dictionary wether there is a method for your specific parameter type.

With this technique you don't have to change other methods or switch/case-statements when adding a new `Provide()` implementation.